# Font awesome icons do not load sometimes

Tags: .htaccess, web, logic, font-awesome

In my web site, 'sometimes' the font awesome icons are not loading. It shows only as squares.

When I googled I found out that to change the .htaccess file in the server. But my web site is hosted in weblogic server. Is there any equivalent to .htaccess file in weblogic.

I encountered this issue only in firefox. But other people have got it in IE 11 as well. In my case, when I clear the cache and open it, it loads also.

Pleade let me know, if anyone understands what's happening here. Thsnks in advance